# Highlight favorite tags on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, tag-highlighting

On the review page on StackOverflow, questions with my favorite tags are not highlighted like they are on the main page.

It would be nice to be able to review questions and answers that I know things about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great idea. This will be the case after the next build.

Comment: I see this has been rolled out, thanks! :-)